# License Management App without being in the AppExchange

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, unlocked-package, lma

Is it possible to receive access to the License Management App without being in the AppExchange?

The scenario would be that I would deploy a managed or unlocked package to a customer environment and have the License Management App control usage and access to that package.

Answer (score 0):

[The LMA doesn't support unlocked packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/lma_associate_package.htm). Managed packages only.

"Being in the AppExchange" can mean a number of different things. To link your package to the LMA, you must have your package available in the Publishing Console in the Partner Community, which means you must be a registered partner and link your namespace org. Your package *does not* have to be listed publicly on the AppExchange in order to use the LMA; you can have a private listing for the package.

I am not certain whether or not you can use the LMA without passing Security Review. However, *you should plan to pass Security Review anyway*, as it provides assurance to your customers and comes with the nice side effect of providing your package with a set of namespace-scoped limits to help ensure it doesn't impact performance in customers' orgs.